# How to run untrusted Javascript code in ReactNative

Tags: javascript, react-native, security, sandbox

I am trying to find a way to run untrusted code on React-Native.

It is known that `eval` and `new Function` are insecure by nature and shouldn't be used.
I looked for alternatives and I see that most of the provided solutions rely on NodeJS.

1. [Node::VM](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v18.x/docs/api/vm.html#vm-executing-javascript)
2. [VM2](https://github.com/patriksimek/vm2)

Unfortunately, I couldn't find any solution that works with React-Native.
Is there any other way that I missed?

Thanks a lot in advance

I tried including Node JS environment into React Native using https://github.com/nodejs-mobile/nodejs-mobile-react-native, but unfortunately I was met with plethora of errors that was very overwhelming. There was also concern about the performance impact of such method.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at a lot of libraries I finally found this library: https://github.com/nyariv/SandboxJS. It had everything I needed and I managed to run it from within React-Native. No need for Node dependency

Comment: How did you use it in RN? To extend the functionality of your app?

Comment: I was receiving JS from the BE to run when certain components in the app are interacted with :)